# Simple XML file to store info

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to create a simple XML file to store some settings that can be easily changed in a text editor. This is my XML file:

```
<connection>
  <hostname>the.host.name</hostname>
  <port>1000</port>
  <database>theDbName</database>
</connection>
```

I am trying to use Linq to XML now to read that info into my program, but it gives me an error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.  'Select' not found.

My code is as follows:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(".\\Resources\\Connection.xml");
string host = from el in root.Element("hostname") select el.Element("text");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(".\\Resources\\Connection.xml");

string host = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("hostname");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused on how your XML structure should look and the way you read that XML with LinQ. First of all place your connection-element in a root called `connections`. Your XML looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connections>
    <connection>
        <hostname>the.host.name</hostname>
        <port>1000</port>
        <database>theDbName</database>
    </connection>
</connections>
```

Now you can select the elements under that root and read all the data from it. Example code looks like following:

```
var root = XElement.Load(".\\Resources\\Connection.xml");
var connection = root.Elements("connection").FirstOrDefault();

if(connection != null)
{
    var host = connection.Element("hostname").Value;
    //do something with 'host'
}
```

**Update:**

If you don't want a root element 'connections', you can omit it and use following code to read the XML:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("G:\\Connection.xml");
var connection = xmlDoc.Descendants("connection").FirstOrDefault();

if(connection != null)
{
    var host = connection.Element("hostname").Value;
    //do something with 'host'
}
```